# Need MYSQL query with good performance to update and import data if that does NOT match criteria move to another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query-optimization, database-performance

I have a database consist of :

- A `loaddata_temp` Table (my main table);
- A `error_data` Table;
- A `company_category` Table;
- A `company_industry` Table;
- A `company_level` Table;
- A `company_type` Table;

here my main table(`loaddata_temp`)

```
company_id  company_name                         company_parent_id  company_type_id  company_category_id  company_industry_id  company_level_id  
----------  -----------------------------------  -----------------  ---------------  -------------------  -------------------  ----------------  
         2  A Plus Lawn Care                                     0          Partner                   PT                  ATL       Head office  
         3  A. L. Price                                          0          Partner                   CV                  ATL       Head office  
         4  A.J. August Fashion Wear                             0          Partner                   UD                  ATL       Head office  
         5  A+ Electronics                                       0          Partner             KOPERASI                  LAT       Head office  
         6  A+ Investments                                       0         Customer               Warung                  AAA       CITY OFFICE  
         7  Aaronson Furniture                                   0            OTHER                   PT                  ATL       Head office  
         8  ABC Markets                                          0             Test                   CV                  ATL       Head office
```

the main table has 8 primary key columns.`company_parent_id`,`company_category_id` and so on(Every column contained an _id is a primary_key)

here one of my refference table

```
company_type_id  company_type_description  
---------------  ------------------------  
              1  Costumer                  
              2  Partner                   
              3  Other                     
             18  Competitor
```

**Background information on what I need to Import data from CSV to Mysql:**

i following this code to import thousand data from csv.

http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-use-mysql-fast-load-data-for-updates-1753.html

link above really help me to improve my query.(thanks to Dawn Rossi)

before insert to the real table(`company`), i need to verified or convert the primary key in `loaddata_temp` into an id.refference from another table like `company_category`,`company_industry` and so on.

so i did the following code below.

```
 $sql_updates[]="UPDATE company 
        LEFT JOIN   loaddata_temp 
        ON      company.company_name = loaddata_temp.company_name
        SET     loaddata_temp.company_name = COALESCE( concat('Error Found Duplicate ',loaddata_temp.company_name),loaddata_temp.company_name)";

$sql_updates[]="UPDATE loaddata_temp 
        LEFT JOIN   demography_country 
        ON  demography_country.demography_country_name = loaddata_temp.demography_country_id
        SET     loaddata_temp.demography_country_id = COALESCE(demography_country.demography_country_id, concat('Error ',loaddata_temp.demography_country_id,' Your Country Not In the List'))";

$sql_updates[]="UPDATE loaddata_temp 
        LEFT JOIN   demography_city 
        ON  demography_city.demography_city_name = loaddata_temp.demography_city_id
        SET     loaddata_temp.demography_city_id = COALESCE(demography_city.demography_city_id,concat('Error ',loaddata_temp.demography_city_id,' : Your city Not In the List'))";

$sql_updates[]="UPDATE loaddata_temp 
        LEFT JOIN   demography_provinces 
        ON  demography_provinces.demography_province_name = loaddata_temp.demography_province_id
        SET     loaddata_temp.demography_province_id = COALESCE(demography_provinces.demography_province_id, concat('Error ',loaddata_temp.demography_province_id,' : Your Province Not In the List'))";
$sql_updates[]="UPDATE loaddata_temp 
        LEFT JOIN   company_type 
        ON  company_type.company_type_description = loaddata_temp.company_type_id
        SET     loaddata_temp.company_type_id = COALESCE(company_type.company_type_id, concat('Error ',loaddata_temp.company_type_id,' : Your company Type Not In the List'))";
$sql_updates[]="UPDATE  loaddata_temp lt
        LEFT JOIN   company_category cc
        ON  cc.company_category_description = lt.company_category_id
        SET     lt.company_category_id = COALESCE(cc.company_category_id, concat('Error ',lt.company_category_id,' : Your Company Category Not In the List'))";
$sql_updates[]="UPDATE loaddata_temp 
        LEFT JOIN   company_level 
        ON  company_level.company_level_description = loaddata_temp.company_level_id
        SET     loaddata_temp.company_level_id = COALESCE(company_level.company_level_id,  concat('Error ',loaddata_temp.company_level_id,' : Your Company Level Not In the List'))";
$sql_updates[]="UPDATE loaddata_temp 
        LEFT JOIN   company_industry 
        ON  company_industry.company_industry_short_description = loaddata_temp.company_industry_id
        SET     loaddata_temp.company_industry_id = COALESCE(company_industry.company_industry_id, concat('Error ',loaddata_temp.company_industry_id,' : Your Company Industry Not In the List'))";
```

from code above the result is

```
company_id  company_name                         company_parent_id  company_type_id  company_category_id  company_industry_id  company_level_id  
----------  -----------------------------------  -----------------  ---------------  -------------------  -------------------  ----------------  
         2  A Plus Lawn Care                                     0                2                    3                    1                 1  
         3  A. L. Price                                          0                1                    4                    5                 1  
         4  A.J. August Fashion Wear                             0                2                    5                    7                 1  
         5  A+ Electronics                                       0                2                   23                Error                 1  
         6  A+ Investments                                       0                1                Error                Error            Errror  
         7  Aaronson Furniture                                   0                3                    3                    1                 1  
         8  ABC Markets                                          0            ERROR                    4                    1                 1
```

from the result above,i need to separate(move) data which has a error into table `error_data` with the following code.

```
INSERT INTO error_data 
    SELECT * FROM loaddata_temp 
    WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(company_name,' ',1)='Error' or
          company_category_id REGEXP '^[A-Za-z \:]+$' OR 
          company_type_id REGEXP '^[A-Za-z \:]+$' OR
          company_industry_id REGEXP '^[A-Za-z \:]+$' OR
          company_level_id REGEXP '^[A-Za-z \:]+$' OR
          demography_city_id REGEXP '^[A-Za-z \:]+$' OR
          demography_country_id REGEXP '^[A-Za-z \:]+$' OR
          demography_province_id REGEXP '^[A-Za-z \:]+$'

DELETE FROM loaddata_temp  
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(company_name,' ',1)='Error' or
              company_category_id REGEXP '^[A-Za-z \:]+$' OR 
              company_type_id REGEXP '^[A-Za-z \:]+$' OR
              company_industry_id REGEXP '^[A-Za-z \:]+$' OR
              company_level_id REGEXP '^[A-Za-z \:]+$' OR
              demography_city_id REGEXP '^[A-Za-z \:]+$' OR
              demography_country_id REGEXP '^[A-Za-z \:]+$' OR
              demography_province_id REGEXP '^[A-Za-z \:]+$'
```

Now in table loaddata_temp there is no data error because it has already moved into table error_data(See Below Table)

```
company_id  company_name                         company_parent_id  company_type_id  company_category_id  company_industry_id  company_level_id  
----------  -----------------------------------  -----------------  ---------------  -------------------  -------------------  ----------------  
         5  A+ Electronics                                       0                2                   23                Error                 1  
         6  A+ Investments                                       0                1                Error                Error            Errror  
         8  ABC Markets                                          0            ERROR                    4                    1                 1
```

**The Problem**

- i need query to rollback error_data table into refference table or an original data without an id.(see below)

  company_id  company_name                         company_parent_id  company_type_id  company_category_id  company_industry_id  company_level_id

  ---

  ```
   5  A+ Electronics                                       0          partner                   23                Error                 1  
   6  A+ Investments                                       0         costumer                Error                Error            Errror  
   8  ABC Markets                                          0            ERROR                    4                    1                 1
  ```
- i need suggestion ABOUT all my code above to make IT prettier and have good performance.
- if there any refference link related my problem please inform me.

  **Your help is gladly appreciated!**

Comment: Could you repeat your question? Do you want to replace the ids with the reference data? You can use the same code as in your `$sql_updates[]` (just `join` instead of `left join` and join on `id` instead of the text). But you might want to think about changing the `loaddata_temp`-table: for e.g. company type have: `company_type`, `company_type_id`. load data into `company_type` (`company_type_id` will stay null), update `company_type_id` (with your `$sql_updates[]`, though you can do this in one big update); rows with `null` in `company_type_id` (or the other id-columns) are erroneous.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I can rephrase the question...  You have a CSV file with strings (such as 'Head office') and you want Normalize those values according to a Normalization table, turning that string into a number (such as '3')?

Further, the CSV file *may* have new strings, so you need to `INSERT` new string-number pairs in the Normalization table?

Then you want to build (or add to) a table that has only the ids (such as '3') not the strings ('Head office').

I discuss a very efficient 2-SQL solution for that task in [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization).  The first SQL discovers and inserts any new rows (`INSERT ... SELECT ... LEFT JOIN ...`).  The second discovers all the ids (`UPDATE ... JOIN ... SET ...`).

(If this is not the thrust of your question, then I have to complain about the lack of simplicity/clarity.)